# When Bootstrapping app using IHostBuilder, Routes return 404

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to bootstrap an ASP.NET Core 7 app using `IHostBuilder` (for testing reasons) like this:

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddEnvironmentVariables()
  .AddCommandLine(args)
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json")
  .Build();

var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();

hostBuilder.AddLogging();
new SerilogLoggerFactory(Log.Logger)
  .CreateLogger<Program>();

hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(
  services => {
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
      );
      services.AddMvc();
  }
);

hostBuilder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
  builder =>
  {
    builder.UseConfiguration(configuration);
    builder.Configure(
      (
        context,
        app
      ) =>
      {
        if (!context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
          app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
          app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(
          endpoints =>
          {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute()
              .RequireAuthorization();
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
);

hostBuilder
  .Build()
  .Run();
```

The application starts without any errors but all routes, e.g. `/` return 404s.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I had to move `builder.ConfigureServices` inside `hostBuilder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults()`:

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddEnvironmentVariables()
  .AddCommandLine(args)
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json")
  .Build();

var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();

hostBuilder.AddLogging();
new SerilogLoggerFactory(Log.Logger)
  .CreateLogger<Program>();

hostBuilder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
  builder =>
  { 
    // moved ConfigureServices call to here:
    builder.ConfigureServices(services  =>
      services => {
      services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
      );
      services.AddMvc();  
    });
    builder.UseConfiguration(configuration);
    builder.Configure(
      (
        context,
        app
      ) =>
      {
        if (!context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
          app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
          app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(
          endpoints =>
          {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute()
              .RequireAuthorization();
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
);

hostBuilder
  .Build()
  .Run();
```